# Filtering array using curl (qBittorrent Web API)

Tags: json, api, curl, post, jq

Hoping someone can help me. I'm trying to understand the [qBittorrent Web API](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/WebUI-API-(qBittorrent-4.1)). At the moment I'm listing all the paused torrents with:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/v2/torrents/info?category=test
```

The problem is that lists the whole JSON array - my question is can I just display the "name" or "hash" fields? This is all using curl through cmd, but I've tried this in Git Bash & Powershell:

```
[{"eta":8640000,"f_l_piece_prio":false,"force_start":false,"hash":"8419d48d86a14335c83fdf4930843438a2f75a6b","last_activity":1664863523,"magnet_uri":"","max_seeding_time":0,"**name**":"TestTorrentName","num_complete":12,"num_incomplete":1,"num_leechs":0,"num_seeds":0,"priority":0,"progress":1,"ratio":0,"ratio_limit":-2,"save_path":"F:\\Completed\\test\\","seeding_time":0,"seeding_time_limit":-2,"seen_complete":1664863523,"seq_dl":false,"size":217388295,"state":"pausedUP","super_seeding":false,"tags":"","time_active":569,"total_size":217388295,"tracker":"udp://open.stealth.si:80/announce","trackers_count":10,"up_limit":-1,"uploaded":0,"uploaded_session":0,"upspeed":0}]
```

I've tried the following that should work according to https://jqplay.org/ - see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfnok.png)

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/v2/torrents/info?category=test | jq --raw-output '.[] | .name'
```

But unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/v2/torrents/info?category=test | jq --raw-output '.[] | .name'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    '.name'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Ti
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
curl -i http://localhost:8080/api/v2/torrents/info?category=test | jq --raw-output '.[] | .name'
```

The `-i` let curl give some header info, that is parsed to `jq`, but `jq` can only parse JSON end therefore fails.

Remove the `-i` and optionally replace it with `-s` to remove the stats:

```
curl -s http://localhost:8080/api/v2/torrents/info?category=test | jq --raw-output '.[] | .name'
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much mate. I noticed the -i and removed it - that fixed the problem for me. Appreciate the answer though.